# Task status always waiting for activation

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api

I'm using this async code for my project:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Area>> GetAreas()
{

        var webclient = new WebClient();
        var result = await webclient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(new Uri(uri)).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Area>>(result);
}


public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var areas = GetAreas();
        Task.WaitAll(areas);
        return View(model: areas);
    }
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14046471/task-waitall-keeps-in-loop) but when i debug my program areas variable have this properties:
status:waiting for activation, method:"", Result : "". 
I know this happen because deadlock async.

please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: await Task.WhenAll(areas)

Comment: I am using .net 4 and visual studio 2010. So i can't find that method.
Thank you

Comment: i found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12515184/is-this-a-correct-net-4-implementation-for-net-4-5s-whenall) but i confuse how implement it in my code. I had tried it and the same problem happen.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
public Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ActionResult>();
    GetAreas().ContinueWith(t => 
    {
      if(t.IsCancelled)
        tcs.SetCancelled();
      else if(t.IsFaulted)
        tcs.SetException(t.Exception);
      else
        tcs.SetResult(new View(model: t.Result); 
    });
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: I had tried it. And i have the same problem. When i debug my code. tcs.Task.Status still "WaitingforActivation". Thanks