# Which .NET version for C# 5 async features

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

Which version of .NET does the user have to have installed on their computer for a developer to use the updated async functionality in C# 5?

Comment: `4.5` ..............

Comment: Not an exact duplicate but this should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4

Comment: @Ramhound: Your understanding is incorrect. It *is* C# 5. If you've got Visual Studio installed, you can find the C# 5 spec somewhere in the installation. (This has happened before - C# 3 shipped with .NET 3.5, not .NET 3.0.)

Comment: @JonSkeet - I looked at Amazon, and found `C# 5.0` books up until Aug, any search for `C# 5.0` was more very speculative hence my confusion.  I had not searched for `C# 5.0` since before Aug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# Async features use classes introduced in .Net 4.5

However, you can also [use the Async Targetting Pack](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx) from NuGet, which includes these classes  for .Net 4.0.

Comment: Note that the Async Targeting Pack is going to be replaced shortly by [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async), which provides support for several *more* platforms.

Answer (score 2):

That depends actually. By default, only .NET 4.5 projects support async/await feature. But with Async targeting pack you can compile .NET 4 projects with Visual Studio 2012 and still use the async/await features.

You can download it from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29576. Please note that this is rather old version, a newer version is expected to be released soon. You can fetch it via NuGet from this link https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async.