# how to use async and await on a method that is time comsuming

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a method like this:

```
public void ButtonClicked()
{
     var MyResult=MyTimeConsumingTask(MyClassProperty); 
 }
```

As you can see, it blocks UI thread.

I can create a backgroundWorker and run this method on that background thread, but I am looking to see if using Async and Await would help me to simplify this.

This is not working:

```
public async void ButtonClicked()
{
    await var MyResult=MyTimeConsumingTask(MyClassProperty); 
}
```

How can I do this?

I like to know the general solution, but also noting that MyimeConsumingTask is waiting for some data on network, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: `var MyResult = await Task.Run(() => MyTimeConsumingTask(MyClassProperty));`

Comment: "This is not working" is never enough information. I suspect you just want `var myResult = await MyTimeConsumingTask(MyClassProperty);` but you should *always* specify the error in the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call any method asynchronously in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563299/how-to-call-any-method-asynchronously-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What do you want to happen when the button is clicked? I assume that something should happen on the UI, when the `MyTimeConsumingTask` has finished? I'm also assuming that the UI should not block?

Comment: @Jonny nothing, since it is not compilable...

Comment: @Stijn I don't believe that is a valid duplicate as this question explicitly asks (badly) about `async/await` which that question doesn't cover (as it was asked before the feature became available).

Comment: @EZI Thanks for answer. What I was missing was the inclusion of Task.Run.. which is working now. Please add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @DanielKelley It does answer the question with the [bottom answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24241619/247702). The answer doesn't use `await`, but that's not necessary here I believe.

Comment: @Stijn That question is not similar as my question was how to use async and await, but the other question was how to use any method to run async.

Comment: Just another question: In other question it say that async and await would be in c#5, but as far as I know it is available in c#4.5 am I wrong?

Comment: @mans sure you asked for `async` and `await` because you thought that was the way to solve it. But really you're asking how to run your method asynchronous.

Comment: @Stijn I also mentioned that I can use backgroundworker to do it, but my question is specifically how to do it using async and await

Comment: @mans fair enough, I'll remove the close vote. Regarding your previous comment, C# 4.5 does not exist. The framework supports it in .NET 4.5 and C# supports the syntax with C# 5 ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13179923/which-net-version-for-c-sharp-5-async-features)).

Comment: Sounds like you simply need to go look at some basic tutorials on the topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be able to *await* `MyTimeConsumingTask` it must be declared to return a *Task*.

```
public async Task<SimeType> MyTimeConsumingTask()
```

Since you said it does some network IO, you can rewrite it using async NW IO methods and then *await* it as

```
var MyResult = await MyTimeConsumingTask(MyClassProperty);
```

But in your case the simplest approach seems to be using `Task.Run`

```
var MyResult = await Task.Run(() => MyTimeConsumingTask(MyClassProperty));
```

---

Comparing these two approaches:

**1.**

```
public async Task<string> GetHtmlAsync(string url)
{
    using (var wc = new Webclient())
    {
        var html = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync(url);
        //do some dummy work and return
        return html.Substring(1, 20);
    }
}

var str1 = await GetHtmlAsync("http://www.google.com");
```

**2.**

```
public string GetHtml(string url)
{
    using (var wc = new Webclient())
    {
        var html = wc.DownloadString(url);
        //do some dummy work and return
        return html.Substring(1, 20);
    }
}

var str2 = await Task.Run(()=>GetHtml("http://www.google.com"));
```

I would definitely prefer the first one, but the 2nd one is easier to use if it is *already working and hard to change* method.