# Await alternative in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, c#-5.0

What would be the best alternative for the await keyword in .NET 4.0 ? I have a method which needs to return a value after an asynchronous operation. I noticed the wait() method blocks the thread completely thus rendering the asynchronous operation useless. What are my options to run the async operation while still freeing the UI thread ?

Comment: use await, but in the right way i guess. You have some code?

Comment: Is it acceptable to use VS2012 with C# 5.0 while targeting .net 4.0? See [Using async-await on .net 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4)

Comment: @CodesInChaos For coworkers, no :).

Comment: Why don't you use continuations?

Comment: What did you use in the end?

Comment: @FelixK. I resorted to the Task's ContinueWith()

Answer (score 4):

I think your basic options are

- Using `Task` and `.ContinueWith()`
- Using the Async [CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9983) and `async` / `await`
- Using [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx)

The easiest way is probably to install the Async CTP. As far as I know the license allows comercial usage. It patches the compiler and comes with a 150kb dll that you can include into your project.

You can use `Task` and `.ContinueWith()`. But that means, that you have to take some effort with exeption handling and flow control.

Tasks are a functional construct. That's why `ContinueWith()` does not mix well with imperative constructs like `for` loops or `try-catch` blocks. Therefore `async` and `await` got introduced, so that the compiler can help us out.

If you can't have that support of the compiler (i.e. you use .Net 4.0), your best bet is to use the [TAP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957) together with a functional framework. [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx) is a very good framework to treat asynchronous methods.

Just google for "reactive extensions tasks" to get started.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a behaviour like `await` with the `yield` coroutines, i'm using this in non-4.5 code. You need a `YieldInstruction` class which is retrieved from the method which should run async:

```
public abstract class YieldInstruction
{
    public abstract Boolean IsFinished();
}
```

Then you need some implementations of the `YieldInstruction` ( a.e. `TaskCoroutine` which handles a task ) and use it this way ( Pseudo code ):

```
public IEnumerator<YieldInstruction> DoAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = ....;
    String result;
    yield return new TaskCoroutine(() => { result = client.DownloadAsync(); });
    // Process result here
}
```

Now you need a scheduler which handles the execution of the instructions.

```
for (Coroutine item in coroutines)  
{  
    if (item.CurrentInstruction.IsFinished())  
    {
         // Move to the next instruction and check if coroutine has been finished 
         if (item.MoveNext()) Remove(item);
    }
}
```

When developing WPF or WinForms applications you are also able to avoid any `Invoke` calls if you are updating the coroutines at the right time. You also might be able to extend the idea to make your life even easier. Sample:

```
public IEnumerator<YieldInstruction> DoAsync()
{
    HttpClient client = ....;
    client.DownloadAsync(..);

    String result;
    while (client.IsDownloading)
    {
        // Update the progress bar
        progressBar.Value = client.Progress;
        // Wait one update
        yield return YieldInstruction.WaitOneUpdate;
    }
    // Process result here
}
```