# Are Tasks included in .NET Framework 4?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0

I met Tasks using .NET Framework 4.5 (with async and await) and I need to know if they are part of  the standard .NET Framework 4.

Comment: Task avaiable from .NET 4.0 and asinca/wait are part of C# 5.0

Comment: I have googled before but I dont know if Task Parallel Library is a standard feature of the .NET Framework 4 or an addon. Sorry to bother you man

Comment: Related: [Using async-await on .net 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and related classes are available in .Net 4. Async and await are part of C# 5, and these rely on methods (e.g. GetAwaiter) which are not defined on `Task` until .Net 4.5. You can use async/await when targeting .Net 4 if you use the [Async targeting pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29576) along with a C# 5 compiler.