# Async HttpWebRequest catch WebException

Tags: c#, asynchronous, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to catch `WebException` from asynchronous `HttpWebRequest` to read soap:fault from api. But it throws `AggregateException`. Is there a way to catch `WebException` for Async `HttpWebRequest` ?

```
public async Task<XDocument> GetXmlSoapResponseAsync(string soapRequestURL, string xmlData)
    {
      try
      {
        //create xml doc
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        //load xml document frtom xmlData
        doc.LoadXml(xmlData);
        //creta web request
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(soapRequestURL);
        req.ContentType = "text/xml";
        req.Accept = "text/xml";
        req.Method = "POST";

        //GetRequestStream from req
        Stream stm = req.GetRequestStream();
        doc.Save(stm);
        stm.Close();

        Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
        req.BeginGetResponse,
        asyncResult => req.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
        (object)null);

        var response = task.Result;
        return await task.ContinueWith(t => ReadStreamFromResponse(response,stm, soapRequestURL,xmlData));
      }
      catch (WebException webException)
      {
        LogWebException(webException, soapRequestURL, xmlData);

        return null;
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
var response = task.Result;
```

to this

```
var response = await task;
```

`await` returns the result of the task *or* unwraps the `AggregateException`, if any.

---

Also, `.Result` blocks the current thread until the result is available, and that's probably not what you want, otherwise you'd just be using the blocking `GetResponse`, instead of the async `BeginGetResponse` and `EndGetResponse`.

*Also*, you don't even need those two methods. There's a better one - `GetResponseAsync`

Use this:

```
var response = await req.GetResponseAsync();
```

Instead of this:

```
Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
req.BeginGetResponse,
asyncResult => req.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
(object)null);

var response = task.Result;
```

Comment: thanks for quick perfect answer and optimizing my codes with await req.GetResponseAsync();. I am new to this async thing and I have to read more to understand it properly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @sanjeev No problem. The `BeginXX` and `EndXX` pair of methods are a part of the [APM - Asynchronous Programming Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963(v=vs.110).aspx) and they were really useful before .NET 4.5. Nowadays, with the introduction of async/await, in *most* situations, you're better of using the `XXAsync` counterpart.

Comment: @sanjeev Also, if you ever need to use an API that has the `Begin`/`End` pair of methods, but doesn't have an `XXAsync` method - then you should use `Task.Factory.FromAsync` to create a task and await it, like you were doing ;) That's a workaround for older APIs.

Comment: Ah great to know about this workaround. I wasn't aware of that. Thanks.

Comment: Shame `await` isn't available in VS 2010.

Comment: @ForeverWintr `await` isn't a visual studio feature, it's a C# feature. Which version are you using?

Comment: Really? [This msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156570(v=vs.110).aspx) suggested to me that it was. `"The Async and Await keywords were introduced in Visual Studio 2012. For information about new features in that version, see What's New in Visual Studio 2012."` I'm using VB.net (10) actually.

Comment: @ForeverWintr Well, that was a really poor choice of words. Visual Studio is an IDE. What they probably meant was - You need the C# 5.0 compiler - and the Visual Studio 2012 installer comes with that compiler. Which version of .NET are you targeting though? You can make it work with VS2012 + .NET 4 by using the `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` package, see this: [Using async-await on .net 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4)

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. The joys of Microsoft documentation. I am targeting .NET 4.0 (because I need to support old versions of MS Office). I'll look into `Microsoft.Bcl.Async`. Thanks for the clarification!