# Closing a ProgressBar at the conclusion of the life a background thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, progress-bar

In my program I am using a separate thread to read from an external file and convey data to my program. I am in the process of trying to run a `ProgressBar` on the UI thread while that thread is running, in order to provide feedback to the user. As of now, I have a `ProgressBar` that opens, but does not close because I do not know how to tell it that the child thread has ended. I have read this tutorial on [ProgressBars](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc-controls/the-progressbar-control/), and should make a note that I am not using a `BackgroundWorker` for my thread. Instead of this, I am just using a `System.Threading.Thread`. Please let me know if this is a problem.

The `OpenFile()` method that opens the Window containing the `ProgressBar`, and also launches the thread that will do the open file work:

```
public void OpenFile()
{
    //Open Progress Bar Window
    LoadingWindow = new LoadingScreen(App.MainWindowViewModel.LoadScreen); 
    LoadingWindow.Show();
    App.MainWindowViewModel.LoadScreen.IsIndeterminate = true;

    FILE_INPUT = true; //bool that Signifies that the background thread is running

    //Create Thread -- run routines in thread
    var openFileThread = new Thread(() => openDefault(txtFile)); //Passes the file
    openFileThread.Start(); //Start File open thread
}

//This thread reads in the file and transfers the data to the program
private void openDefault(StreamReader txtFile)
{
    //Gathers info from file and changes program accordingly

    FILE_INPUT = false; //background thread is no longer running
}
```

As of now, I do not have an increment method for my `ProgressBar`, as I would like to make sure that I can get it working correctly before working on a technical detail like that. Anyway, my question is... how and where in my program do I make it known that the background thread is done running and the `LoadingWindow` (`ProgressBar`) can be closed?

Some more code to help give you an idea of my program's flow:

Main Window Code Behind:

```
private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFile(); //calls to the method that launches the new thread and the window with the Progress Bar

    //Wait until background Thread is complete
    while (ViewModel.FILE_INPUT == true) { }

    //After thread has stopped running, close the window (DOES NOT WORK)
    ViewModel.LoadingWindow.Close(); // -- Close Prog Bar
}
```

Eventual **Solution:**

```
//In OpenFile() method
LoadingWindow = new LoadingScreen(App.MainWindowViewModel.LoadScreen); //Open Progress Bar Window
LoadingWindow.Show();
App.MainWindowViewModel.LoadScreen.IsIndeterminate = true;

FILE_INPUT = true; //A file is being inputted*

Dispatcher UIDispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;

Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
     openDefault(txtFile); //Passes the file
     //After thread has stopped running, close the Loading Window
     UIDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => LoadingWindow.Close())); //Close progress bar
});
```

Comment: Why not use BackgroundWorker?  It has the events you need.

Comment: Probably just because of my lack of total knowledge of the WPF platform. I assumed that `BackgroundWorker` was equivalent to a system `Thread`. I will look at converting it.

Comment: BackgroundWorker uses threads and has the events you want,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a complete code example, it's hard to provide a complete answer. Depending on how you're actually doing the file I/O and managing the `ProgressBar`, there might be other changes you could make to also improve the code. But to solve the immediate problem, I recommend taking advantage of the `async`/`await` pattern:

```
public async Task OpenFile()
{
    //Open Progress Bar Window
    LoadingWindow = new LoadingScreen(App.MainWindowViewModel.LoadScreen); 
    LoadingWindow.Show();
    App.MainWindowViewModel.LoadScreen.IsIndeterminate = true;

    FILE_INPUT = true; //bool that Signifies that the background thread is running

    //Create Thread -- run routines in thread
    await Task.Run(() => openDefault(txtFile)); //Passes the file
}

private async void OpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    await OpenFile(); //calls to the method that launches the new thread and the window with the Progress Bar

    //After thread has stopped running, close the window
    ViewModel.LoadingWindow.Close(); // -- Close Prog Bar
}
```

This will avoid causing your UI to freeze while the operation is working, while allowing the code to be written in a simple, straight-through manner.

It's possible that with the above changes, you can get rid of your `FILE_INPUT` variable altogether (it's not clear for what else you might be using it, but it might be nothing else).

Note that the `OpenFile()` method is changed to return `Task`. This is the norm for `async` methods without an actual return value. The same change *would* be made to the `OpenFile_Click()` method, except that as an event handler, these are generally required to return `void`. Either syntax is legal, but the former is preferred when possible so that access to the `Task` object is possible (for exception handling, completion, etc.).

**EDIT:** for those without .NET 4.5 and who cannot install the necessary components to support `async`/`await` (which is just a compile-time change), here's an example that will work in .NET 4.0:

```
public void OpenFile()
{
    //Open Progress Bar Window
    LoadingWindow = new LoadingScreen(App.MainWindowViewModel.LoadScreen); 
    LoadingWindow.Show();
    App.MainWindowViewModel.LoadScreen.IsIndeterminate = true;

    FILE_INPUT = true; //bool that Signifies that the background thread is running

    //Create Thread -- run routines in thread
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        openDefault(txtFile); //Passes the file
        //After thread has stopped running, close the window
        Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => ViewModel.LoadingWindow.Close())); // -- Close Prog Bar
    });
}

private void OpenFile_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //calls to the method that launches the new thread and the window with the Progress Bar
    OpenFile();
}
```

(This is actually semantically a little different from the `async`/`await` implementation, in that rather than creating a continuation for the first task, I just put the window-close operation in that task. But it should have the same net result).

Comment: You can still use `async`/`await` in .NET 4.0 if you are willing to upgrade the relevant components: [Using async-await on .net 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4). That said, you can accomplish a similar effect without it. I'll add an example to my answer.

Comment: I'm trying the code you put up in your edit section, and I'm getting an error for the `Dispatcher.Invoke(() => LoadingWindow.Close());` part that says: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type`. Are we not allowed to use a `Window` object in there?

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I forgot that you also don't have the new overloads for `Invoke()` in .NET 4.0. I'll update the example.

Comment: Is `Action` just a generic that I need to fill in, because with the new example I get `An object reference is required for the non-static field....`

Comment: Since the method isn't static, the error message is still puzzling. Maybe it's complaining about something different. This is why the question should include a complete code example.

Comment: This was just an error due to my lack of knowledge. I solved it by creating a `Dispatcher` object and using that one. I'll update my answer with the solution that I used.