# Unknown WebService description and consume it from C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I'm quite a noob and have been developing 'seriously' (as my job) from a couple of months barely, so i apologize in advance for my ignorance.

There is this web service that i need to consume from a C# client on an aspx page I want to develop, but first I need to understand the webservice, I'm not sure which language it's made upon but I think it's PERL, since the web service's URL is like this "http://wschsol.mideplan.cl/mod_perl/xml/fps-by-rut". This webservice was developed by other people which i cannot contact right now and is running on a linux server to which i don't have access either.

The webservice's job is pretty simple, it receives a person's national ID number and returns some information about him on xml format, which i want to show on my client aspx page with some grids and stuff.

I have read around the internet that it's possible to see a description of a webservice and its methods using the WSDL variable after the common ".asmx" extension, but in this case there is no extension and so, i can't use the the ?WSDL. I'm guessing that maybe "fps_by_rut" is only a webmethod, and not the webservice itself. So the question is: how do I use the webservice? 
Since I know what kind of request is expected (a person's ID), I tried to manually add an ID to the URL through the browser (like this: "http://wschsol.mideplan.cl/mod_perl/xml/fps-by-rut?rut=6985462-1") and if I do it responds normally in xml format.

I tried to add a web service reference for it on my project, but well, i pasted the whole URL and when I click "go" it says it needs credentials. I have these credentials, a user and password, but they are not working... what confuses me is that there is another client to this same webservice programmed on classic asp made by the guy before me here, and i can acces that code, and when i see the line on which he calls the web service it's like this:

```
xml.Open "GET", "http://wschsol.mideplan.cl/mod_perl/xml/fps-by-rut?rut="&rsVac(0), False,"user","password"
```

i have censored the "user" and "password" strings since those are the actual credentials. This classic asp client works fine with those credentials. I tried to use those when creating the reference, but they are not working. Even more, when i manually added the ID through the browser it asked me for credentials and they worked too...

Am I going the wrong way? Please guys, i need guidance. If there is a course out there which I can read that helps me understand all of this webservices stuff, i'd be hugely grateful. Or if someone can tell me which way to go, I'm pretty sure I'm in the wrong direction...

Thanks in advance for any help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WSDL is used for SOAP and we both don't know if it's an SOAP-Service.
You should just use a `HttpClient` and make your Get-Calls to the API.
You can use something like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://wschsol.mideplan.cl");
var httpResponse = await client.GetStringAsync("mod_perl/xml/fps-by-rut?rut=<InsertParamHere>");
```

Edit Authorization:
You have to add this:

```
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password1234");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));
```

Snippet source: [Simple C# .NET 4.5 HTTPClient Request Using Basic Auth and Proxy](http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/13895/Simple-C---NET-4-5-HTTPClient-Request-Us)

Comment: Sounds pretty good but, what's gonna happen with the authentication? When manually adding the ID param through the browser it did ask for credentials; so when my httpclient attempts to connect, won't the server ask for the credentials??

Comment: I'v modified the post for authorization

Comment: I'm having some issues with the "await" command, it says it doesn't exist on the current instance; am i missing something? I checked the "usings" and they're all OK.

Comment: Which Version are you using? 4.5?

Comment: 4; but i've got the System.Net.Http package through the NuGet extension.

Comment: In 4.0 you need this package to get access to async/await (introduced in 4.5) : https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async or look there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4

Comment: Yeah i solved that already, I'm using the "ContinueWith" method instead of await. Right now I'm stuck on this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258722/cant-assign-an-http-response-content-into-an-xml-document-on-c-sharp. Thanks dude for your assistance!