# Can't assign an http response content into an xml document on C#

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, dotnet-httpclient

Ok there is this webservice that I need to consume from which I know nothing about, all I know is what it's meant to do: it receives a person's national ID number and returns some information about him on xml format. I need to consume it from a C# client on an aspx page.

Since I couldn't create a web reference to the WS, I came to SO and asked this first:
[Unknown WebService description and consume it from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27174662/unknown-webservice-description-and-consume-it-from-c-sharp)

On that question I was suggested to rather make an HttpClient instead of a reference, so I started googling around and learned some stuff; right now I've been able to do this:

```
protected void rutBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //This function triggers when the user clicks the button 
    {                                                   //aside the textbox where they're meant to input the ID number
        if (rutTB.Text != "")   //rutTB is the textbox aside the button
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); // Here i'm creating an instance of an HTTP client
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:password123"); //Load credentials into a byte array (censored since there should be the actual credentials)
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://wschsol.mideplan.cl"); //Base address of the web-service
            var hResp = "mod_perl/xml/fps_by_rut?rut=" + rutTB.Text; //Creating a variable that holds the rest of the WS's URL with the ID number value added to it
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)); //Server authentication header with the byte array turned into a string
            client.GetAsync(hResp).ContinueWith( //Here I'm sending the GET request to the WS
                (requestTask) =>
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage resp = requestTask.Result;    //This task receives the WS's http response and assigns it to a HttpResponseMessage variable called resp
                        try
                        {
                            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); //This line is to check that the response was successful or else throw an exception
                            XmlDocument xmlResp = new XmlDocument(); //Creating an instance of an xml document
                            resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync<XmlDocument>().ContinueWith(  //OK HERE IS WHERE I'M LOST AT, trying to take the content of the http response into my xml document instance
                            (readTask) =>
                            {
                                /* This is where i want to parse the xml document data obtained into some grids or something. */
                            });
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
                        }
                    });

        }
        else
        {
            testLBL.Text = "You must enter an RUT number"; // Error label
            testLBL.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

The code line on which I'm lost at is underlined by my VS2010. I know this line is wrong, I based myself on this snippet https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/introduction-to-httpclient-4a2d9cee; the guy there loads the response onto a JsonArray instead of an XML Document. So i'd be greatly thankful if you guys could tell me how to get that code line right, and if something else is wrong in my function. Anyways, the webservice's response comes through the browser on XML format, so maybe I don't even need to convert it to an xml document?? I'm pretty lost, i'm quite a noob yet at software development so i'll be hugely grateful if you guys can help me out.

Thank you guys for your kind assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument doc;
t.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(
    (streamTask) =>
    {
        doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(streamTask.Result);
     });
```

Then, graduate to this:

```
var xmlStream = await t.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlStream);
```

In .NET 4.5, use "await" instead of "ContinueWith" when possible.

Comment: P.S.  I tried to use ReadAsAsync<XmlDocument>() but it doesn't seem to work.  That would be even simpler though.

Comment: Apparently it worked, but I want to know (before getting into the parsing job) if my xmlDocument is correctly receiving the same data that's shown on the browser as xml when the webservice is called... how can i do that?? I put some breakpoints (on the stream task and on the xml load instruction, but when i check the XmlDocument object i can't seem to find anything on it. Any ideas???

Comment: Then replace ReadAsStreamAsync() with ReadAsStringAsync().  That makes it easy to put a breakpoint in there and see the string, or to write it out to the console.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to check it as Stream, but for some reason my xmlDocument is getting the response into an attribute called "InnerXml"; right there (doc.InnerXml) is the whole xml response, as if it was just a long string, and i've got no childs or names or tags; all other attributes are empty or null, no IEnumerable either... what did i do wrong?

Comment: That's what InnerXml is.  It is the whole XML as a string.  It will be the original string that you got from the HTTP request, including any child tags etc, in canonical XML form.  Is the InnerXml somehow different from what was in the raw stream?

Comment: No, it's exactly the same... But i was planning to use the "GetElementsByTagName" method to populate a list of xml nodes, since my xmldocument object has no "names" it's not gonna work :/ idk what to do now.

Comment: hmm, ok.  I am really curious as to your XML since I am not sure how an XML document can have no tag names.  But I think the contents of your XML are really part of another discussion and the question of "how to load the HTTP result into XML" is answered.  Not sure what else I can do for you on that front.  Sorry!

Comment: Sure man, the base question did get an answer, thank you very much :) the XML data is ok, the tags do have names, it's just that i don't see them as attributes of the XmlDocument object, they're into the innerXml along with everything else. What about using the GetEnumerator" method for the xmldocument object to see if it gets the attributes?

Comment: Seven years late, but I had a similar problem with the xml tags going missing. The solution for me was to add client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/xml"); to tell the server that I wanted my response in XML format, instead of some other bizarre data format that it sent otherwise.