# Can't use XmlNodeList loaded inside a task from outside the task

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, web-services, dotnet-httpclient

Ok here I am once again. I need to consume a webservice from a C# client i'm trying to develop. I'm working with HttpClient (from .NET 4.5) BUT I'm on **.NET 4**, I got these Http packages from NuGet. I know nothing about the WS except two things: what it does (receives a person's national ID number and returns some information about him/her on xml format), and the credentials asked by the server to use it.

So my function looks something like this:

```
protected void rutBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //This void function triggers when the user clicks the button 
    {                                                   //aside the textbox where they're meant to input the ID number.
        if (rutTB.Text != "")                           //"rutTB" is the textbox aside the button
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();                       //Here i'm creating an instance of an HTTP client
            var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user:pass123"); //Load credentials into a byte array (obviously censored since that's where the actual credentials go
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://wschsol.mideplan.cl"); //Base address of the web-service
            var par = "mod_perl/xml/fps-by-rut?rut=" + rutTB.Text;      //Creating a variable that holds the rest of the WS's URL
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray)); //Server authentication header with the byte array turned into a string
            client.GetAsync(par).ContinueWith(                          //Sending the GET request to the WS
                (requestTask) =>
                    {
                        HttpResponseMessage resp = requestTask.Result;  //This task receives the WS's http response and assigns it to a HttpResponseMessage variable
                        try
                        {
                            resp.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();             //This line is to check that the response was successful or else throw an exception
                            XmlDocument xmlResp = new XmlDocument();    //Creating an instance of an xml document
                            requestTask.Result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ContinueWith(
                            (streamTask) =>
                            {
                                xmlResp.Load(streamTask.Result);                         //Loading the result stream into an XmlDocument object
                                xmlResp.GetEnumerator();                                 //Not really sure if this is needed.
                                XmlNodeList xmlLst = xmlResp.GetElementsByTagName("dv"); //Loading a list of xml nodes with the elements from the xml object of the type "dv"
                            });
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
                        } 
                    });
            testLBL.Text = "Got here";             //This is to know if the execution reached this point, and it did.
            testLBL.Visible = true;
            dvLBL.Text = xmlLst.Item(0).InnerText; //HERE is the problem. VS tells me that the "xmlLst" name doesn't exist on the current context
            dvLBL.Visible = true;                  //This label was meant to show the value of the 0 indexed item from the list. 
        }
        else
        {
            testLBL.Text = "You must enter an RUT number"; // Error label
            testLBL.Visible = true;
        }
    }
```

the problem is that when I try to obtain data from the xmldocument object it's like it doesn't exist; or rather exists but ONLY when the execution is going INSIDE the streamTask. I'm not sure how to handle this. By now I just want ONE value from ONE tag out of the webservice's response to be shown on a label i've got on my aspx page under the textbox, just to know I'm going the right way, before i get myself into the xml parsing stuff; but it's not working.

I also tried placing the last 4 instructions (the ones that give value to the labels and make them visible) INSIDE the streamTask, and when I do they work, they retrieve the data and assign it to the elements, but I can see it only when debugging with breakpoints, it's not showing on my page on the browser.

Thank you guys in advance for the kind assistance you've given me through this.

*P.S.: Just in case it might be useful, this is my story (question before this one on the same topic) [Can't assign an http response content into an xml document on C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258722/cant-assign-an-http-response-content-into-an-xml-document-on-c-sharp).*

Answer (score 0):

Move your `XmlNodeList xmlLst` declaration outside the task. The `client.GetAsync` operates on it's own scope hence why when you try to access xmlLst outside you get the exception. So you new code should like something like this:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
XmlNodeList xmlLst;
```

Then inside the `GetAsync()`

```
xmlLst = xmlResp.GetElementsByTagName("dv");
```

This should do it.

Comment: I thought about that after asking, and right now it is outside, just as you said, i'm instantiating it as "= null"; then the execution flow enters the task and loads the xmlNodeList, but then outside the task when i try to assign the value of the first item on a label I get a nullpointer exception, because the XmlNodeList is.. still null? or null once again? i don't know.

Comment: And if you debug inside the GetAsync() you can see the xmlLst being populated? Have you removed the second initialization?

Comment: Yes, and yes. The list is populated. I put a breakpoint right after it and it is populated. after that i'm not sure if it "unpopulates", or maybe it's another object that's got the same name, since the task has its own scope...