# How can I produce a Task<Task> to Unwrap

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

Can someone please explain the difference between these two statements:

```
Task<Task> bTask = backup.BackupCurrentDatabaseAsync()
    .ContinueWith(_ => CompressArchiveAsync());
//unwrap the tasks to produce one entire task
Task t = bTask.Unwrap();
```

vs

```
Task<Task> bTask = backup.BackupCurrentDatabaseAsync()
    .ContinueWith(_ => 
{
    CompressArchiveAsync();
});
//unwrap the tasks to produce one entire task
Task t = bTask.Unwrap();
```

The methods`ExtractArchiveAsync()`, `BackupCurrentDatabaseAsync()`, `RestoreDatabaseAsync()` all return a `Task`.

Here, the first Continuation returns a `Task<Task>`. I can then `Unwrap()` this task to put Continuations on the resultant (inner) task.

The second version doesn't compile. The only different here is the braces around the `CompressArchiveAsync()`.

I am trying to access the resultant (internal) `Task` to check the `Task.Status`. If I use the second method, the Task.Status is reporting the result of the `BackupCurrentDatabaseAsync()` task.

Comment: Side note: consider moving to 4.5 and async/awiat if possible... Will produce easier to read code...

Comment: Unfortunately still on 4! How would the above be achieved in 4.5?

Comment: `async`/`await` is mainty a C# 5.0 feature. While it only works out of the box when targeting .NET 4.5, you can use the async targeting pack to [port it to .NET 4.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
.ContinueWith(_ => CompressArchiveAsync());
```

is equivalent to:

```
.ContinueWith(_ => 
{
    return CompressArchiveAsync();
});
```

Notice the `return`.

Your second code snippet doesn't compile because `ContinueWith` doesn't return a `Task<Task>`, but simply a `Task`, and there's nothing to unwrap.

The following is bound to a `Func<Task, Task>` (a function that takes a `Task` and returns a `Task`)

```
_ => 
{
    return CompressArchiveAsync();
}
```

But the following is actually bound to an `Action<Task>` (a function that takes a `Task` but doesn't return anything):

```
_ => 
{
    CompressArchiveAsync();
}
```

And the reference to the `Task` created by `CompressArchiveAsync` is never returned. Without a reference to it, you can't check the `Task`'s status.

Note that:

- [`ContinueWith<TResult>(Func<Task, TResult>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321405.aspx) returns a `Task<TResult>`
- [`ContinueWith(Action<Task>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270696.aspx) returns a `Task`.

Therefore your `ContinueWith(Func<Task, Task>)` returns a `Task<Task>` that you can unwrap, but your `ContinueWith(Action<Task>)` simply returns a `Task`.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in the Lambda Expression syntax.

There are 2 types of Lambdas: **Expression Lambdas** and **Statement Lambdas**. Expression Lambdas have no braces and return the result of the expression while Statement Lambdas have braces containing zero or more statements (one of them can be a `return` statement).

So this Expression Lambda:

```
_ => CompressArchiveAsync()
```

Is equivalent to this Statement Lambda:

```
_ => { return CompressArchiveAsync(); }
```

So, the difference is that in the first continuation you are returning a task but in the second you are not, it's just a void anonymous delegate. That's why the first continuation is a `Task<Task>` while the second is just a `Task`.

Answer (score 2):

Long comment to show 4.5 code.

If you could move to .Net 4.5 than code you are trying to write can be rewritten in more compact way with async/await which is essentially implements all that code internally:

```
 async Task CompleteBackup()
 {
    await backup.BackupCurrentDatabaseAsync()
    await CompressArchiveAsync());
    await .....
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Alexei, If I have `TaskContinuationOptions` associated with my `ContinueWith()`'s, would this method be more verbose?

Comment: @Simon If you need very detailed control over tasks you'll likely need to still use `ContinueWith` and similar calls directly. I have not done it so no direct advice.

Comment: @Simon: I recommend you use this `await`-based code. You can use it with .NET 4.0 Desktop by installing the [Microsoft.Bcl.Async package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/). With `await`, all the appropriate `TaskContinuationOptions` are already provided, and there is no need for that level of control.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary - thank you, I will take the advise from the task master

Comment: Nitpicking: async/await is C#5 feature (which targets .NET 4.5+, but as Stephen Cleary mentioned can also be used on .NET 4.0 with that package)

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are calling `ContinueWith` with a `Func`. Therefore, it will return a `Task<T>`. The second try will call the `ContinueWith` overload with an `Action`, because... well it's an action, it does not return anything. So it will return a simple `Task` without `T`.