# await Task vs await Task.Run(voidMethod)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm confused why the output of these 2 programs differs:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        await LongProcess();
    }
}

private async Task LongProcess()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    progressBar1.Value += 3;
}
```

and

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => LongProcess());
    }
}

private async void LongProcess()
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    progressBar1.Value += 3;
}
```

I realize the first example returning `Task` is more correct, but I don't understand why wrapping the void function in a `Task.Run` doesn't produce the same output?  The first function does what I expect, updates the progress bar every 1 second.  The second code attempts to update the progress bar all at once, causing problems attempting to update the same UI element from multiple threads.

My assumption was since the buttonClick method awaits the long process to complete, both sets of code should not allow the progressBar1 update to happen until the previous process has completed.  Why does the second set of code allow it to happen all at once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This isn't doing what you think it is:

```
await Task.Run(() => LongProcess());
```

The code is awaiting `Task.Run()`, but nothing *within* that task is awaiting `LongProcess()`.  So `Task.Run()` returns immediately in this case.

This is actually an interesting illustration of a failure to be "async all the way down", because the inline function is essentially *hiding* the fact that it's async.  And in fact the compiler *should* be warning you that nothing is awaiting `LongProcess()` and that it would return immediately.

Contrast it with this:

```
await Task.Run(async () => await LongProcess());
```

---

**Edit:** I just noticed why the compiler probably isn't warning you.  Because of this:

```
async void
```

Never, ever, ever do this :)  (Well, ok, there's *one* valid reason to do this.  And I'm sure it haunts the C# team to this day that they had to support it just for that one reason.  But unless you encounter that one reason, don't do it.)

Always return a `Task` for async methods so that the method can be awaited.

Comment: You wouldn't get any warning anyway because if `LongProcess` returned a `Task`, the `Task.Run` overload used would then be `Task Task.Run(Func<Task>)` which *unwraps* the `Task` instead of returning `Task<Task>`.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Are you sure?  I'm testing this now in VS2013 where my `LongProcess` is a simple `async Task Foo() { await Task.Yield(); }` and when I call it in the same way as the OP's code I get a warning in VS.

Comment: `await Task.Run(() => Foo());` yields no warning for me, it's strange you get one.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski: Interesting, I just found the difference.  `await Task.Run(() => { Foo(); });` yields the warning.  I forgot that I'd wrapped it in `{}` when I added the `await` and didn't remove them when reverting for this test.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's a typical mistake, I [wrote a whole answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27530043/3764814) on that one once ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In the first program, LongProcess returns a `Task`, and `Task.Run` is wrapping it -- basically just launching it in the default scheduler rather than whatever context you're currently on.

You'll notice that `Task.Run` has overloads specifically to do this wrapping, and is not returning a `Task<Task>`.

In the second program, LongProcess is an `async void` method, which means `Task.Run` has nothing to wrap and will complete more or less immediately, and before the work is guaranteed to be done.