# Waiting on All Task Threads without having the Task Object

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, c#-4.0, continuewith

I have an application using `.NET 4.0` (so no `async`/`await` available). I am writing tests for a method that uses service calls.

So for example, my test calls `method A`. `Method A` has an async service call to `method B` which returns a `Task` and we do all the processing in `ContinueWith`. `Method A` returns nothing.

The problem is that the main thread reaches the `Assert` call before the `ContinueWith` has a chance to finish so the test fails.

The way to get around this currently is doing `Thread.Sleep(10)` so that the `ContinueWith` has time to execute. This however poses plenty of issues, such as wasting time (which adds up when having hunders - thousands of tests) to tests failing on slower machines.

**I would like to know if there is any way to do a sort of `Thread.WaitAll()` without actually having the `Task` objects as there's no way to get them.** Changing the code is not an option so it must be done from the tests.

Note: I am aware of methods to do it if we have the `Task`/`Thread` objects, but I don't have access to them, so please do not mark it as a duplicate of those as it is not.

Comment: I would think you'd need to do the same thing here as you would with `async/await` which is to let the `Task`s bubble up.  Is there a reason you cannot make `Mathod A` return the Task that results from the `ContinueWith` so that the caller can decided to wait on it?

Comment: Can't you have `Method A` return the `Task` from `ContinueWith`?

Comment: Also, to point out Task and async/await are two separate things. Task was part of .NET since 4.0 and can be used without async. Its just async/await makes it's use much easier.

Comment: I can't because many of those make multiple Task calls (e.g. loading some objects and then enriching them with data from various places). Furthermore, some of them return the objects that are being enriched in the background for display so can't replace that with the task.

Comment: how about using a timer, say, check for every 5 seconds until `Method B` returns something?

Comment: I believe your test has shown to you that your implementation is flawled. If you need to wait for the task to complete in your test, then is also obvious that you could need to wait the same task in real-life occasions. Not returning a task is the wrong choice if this is your scenario.

Comment: @GeomanYabes not all the methods return something so can't really do that.

Comment: @FedericoDipuma this is a GUI, the user wants to see the data as quick as possible even if incomplete and the data gets populated as it comes in. Implementation is fine for what we need.

Comment: @VladSchnakovszki, you said "***...`method B` which returns a Task...***"

Comment: Just because Method A is calling multiple sub-tasks doesn't make it impossible to use .NET 4.0 library methods to compose those tasks into single one. It just won't be as pretty as with async/await. Also, you can use back-port of async/await into .NET : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110472/using-async-await-on-net-4

Comment: About the UI and responsiveness. You sure you want to use Tasks and not Reactive Observables : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET ?

Comment: @Euphoric there is a planned upgrade of .NET so no point in starting to use backports. Let's ignore async/await for this question. As I said, can't really touch the code much either as it would require a lot of regression testing.

Comment: So you are willing to have some dirty hack instead of redesigning your solution to use proper tools? If yes, then I want nothing to do with this.

Comment: *"Implementation is fine for what we need"* - this does not seem to be true if you are having troubles even in writing a simple test.

Comment: @Euphoric It's a *huge* project, redesigning is really not feasible at all. Let's focus on the question in bold above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to know if there is any way to do a sort of Thread.WaitAll() without actually having the Task objects as there's no way to get them.

No, there is not a way to do this reliably.